# How to show the payment which is assigned to user in html page of django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have edited my question. Could someone seriously answer this question? I just want to show the balance of each user in browser whenever he/she logs in.

**models.py**

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Balance'
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def balance(request):
    balances = Balance.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    for field in balances:
        field.amount

    context = {
        'balances': balances
    }
    return render(request, 'users/balance.html', context)
```

**HTML page**

```
<h2>Your Balance is: {{balances.amount}}</h2>
```

**Image of database which contains content**

```
https://ibb.co/481nzqv
```

Comment: You made it right in the sense of coding, but you probably didn't assign the correct user to that Payment instances, at least you're accessing a different user in your template. Check with the following in models:  `[payment.owner.id for payment in Payment.objects.all()]` and in the template `{{numbers1.payment_numbers}} - {{numbers1.owner.id}}`.

Comment: Is there anyone to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You render the value with:

```
{{ numbers1.payment_numbers }}
```

But here `numbers1` is a `Payment` object you passed to the template, so a single element, not the aggregate over the payments.

The for loop is useless as well, since you only iterate over objects, and retrieve the `.payment_numbers` value, but you do not do anything with these values. Even if it would work, it is not advisable to calculate aggregates at the Python/Django level anyway.

But the main problem originates from the fact that the modeling does not look ok.

---

The modeling does not look to make much sense. You probably want to store the amount in the `Payment` objects. This is likely a [**`DecimalField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield), or some other numerical field. By using a `CharField`, you can not calculate the sum of these fields at the database side, or at least not without a lot of casting, etc.

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can calculate aggregates over these fields, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from decimal import Decimal

def payment(request):
    total_amount = Payment.objects.filter(
        owner=request.user
    ).aggregate(
        total_amount=Sum('amount')
    )['total_amount'] or Decimal('0.00')
    context = {
        'total_amount ': total_amount 
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

The `or Decimal('0.00')` here will ensure that if you sum over an empty queryset, it will use zero, not `None`.

We can then render this with:

```
<li style="float: right;">Your Balance: Rs. {{ total_amount }}</li>
```

Comment: @ipaleka: well in short, a `CharField` is not designed to hold numerical data. All else that is done to "circumvent" that, will only make matters worse in the future. A lot of Django questions here boil down to bad modeling. My own experience is that if you do not fix the modeling, eventually it results in more more "pain" than fixing it now :). If you want to write an answer for a `CharField`, I would say go ahead :)

Comment: That's fine, but it doesn't answer nor explain why the data isn't shown in the template. Your answer would be perfect if you tried to locate the problem first, propose the solution and then add this answer as the iceing on the cake. NHF

Comment: Hey Willem, I applied but it is not giving me the amount which I have saved in database in my browser page.

Comment: The problem with `{{numbers1.payment_numbers}}` in the original template is just in the naming, but it should iterate and show all the Payment instances for the current user sent as `receiving1` in context and looped with `{% for numbers1 in receiving1 %}`.

Comment: @ipaleka: aarghh... yes, somehow I read over the `{% for ... %}` thanks.

Comment: I didn't use ```{% for ... %}```  Willem

Comment: @Adnan: in the original template, it looks like you did use `{% for ... %}`, but indeed, in the one in this answer you should *not* iterate.

Comment: I used the ```for loop```, then I didn't use ```for loop```. In both cases it is not working.

Comment: @Adnan: the idea is that you used a `{% for ... %}` loop, and thus you iterate over the items, not over an aggregate. But regardless whether you used/did not use a `for` loop, it would indeed not yield the correct results.

Comment: Willem how could I make you believe I deleted the ```for loop``` from my template now. And I am not using it.

Comment: You said whether I used/didn't use a for loop, it would indeed not yield the correct results. Then what is the solution here?

Comment: @Adnan: no, the solution proposed should be the correct one. Ipaleka and me were talking about what the problem was with the *original* implementation (the one in your question).

Comment: I have used the solution you have given but it didn't show me ```amount.```

Comment: @Adnan: amount or `total_amount`. Can you edit your question and show the database content?

Comment: I have edited my question and gave the links of images in which data is stored in mongodb.

Comment: @Adnan: what is the output?

Comment: Output is ```Your Balance is: Rs.``` After Rs. nothing appears

Comment: @Adnan: and what user id do you use?

Comment: @Adnan: If you want to display zero for users with no `Payment` objects, you can add `or Decimal('0.00')` as in the edit.

Comment: Balance is showing nothing neither zero nor the balance I have added.

Comment: @Adnan: you did change the context to `'total_amount ': total_amount`, can you `print(total_amount)` before you render the template.

Comment: I changed the context as you said and I tried but don't know how to ```print(total_amount)``` before rendering the template?

Comment: @Adnan: you just call `print(total_amount)` before calling `render(..)` in the view.

Comment: @Adnan: then it looks like you are not triggering that view in the first place. A `print(..)` should always print something.

Comment: ```<QuerySet [<Balance: Balance object (1)>, <Balance: Balance object (2)>]>``` It showed.

Comment: @Adnan: but the model was a `Payment`?

Comment: I don't want to sum, max etc b/w total amount. I changed the model to balance

Comment: @Adnan: so if you have two `Payment`s for a user, what do you want to do to calculate the total amount?

Comment: @Adnan: but then the modeling is wrong, since then your `Payment` is basically a "Balance" object. This then should have a `OneToOneField` to the user. Furthermore it would introduce *data duplication*, since you store both records and aggregates, which is a severe anti-pattern.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197931/discussion-on-answer-by-willem-van-onsem-how-to-show-the-payment-which-is-assign).